# how can I force intellij to order autocomplete options just alphabetically?

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete

The problem is:

IntelliJ shows fields or methods after I type dot (.), but when I select one of them, IntelliJ moves selected item to top of items regardless of alphabetic order.
Then when I need to call all methods of an instance (for example), it is possible to forget call some methods because every time I select an items, their order will be changed

how can disable intellij idea autocomplete optimization and force it to order autocomplete options just alphabetically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to sort the auto complete options lexicographically.

You can set this as the default behaviour using `Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion`. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

You can also set this by clicking on the icon in the bottom right hand corner of the auto complete display. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

More information [in the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea//2017.1/code-completion-2.html).